# Как окрасить верхнюю панель браузера при помощи мета-тэгов?

Tags: html

Как окрасить верхнюю панель браузера при помощи мета-тэгов?

Comment: Насколько я знаю - никак. Из самого браузера вам можно изменить только заголовок

Answer (score 0):

> Как окрасить верхнюю панель браузера при помощи мета-тэгов?

Чтобы не скрывалось под "верхней панелью браузера" это, к счастью, невозможно. Подобные вмешательства запрещены по условиям безопасности.

Comment: Щас бы какой-то сайт превратил мой браузер в дискотеку).

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать только для некоторых мобильных браузеров и то, если там разрешена такая возможность.

```html
<!-- Chrome, Firefox OS and Opera -->
<meta name="theme-color" content="#4285f4">
<!-- Windows Phone -->
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#4285f4">
<!-- iOS Safari -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#4285f4">
```

Но я уже очень давно не видел, чтобы это хоть где-то работало на новых версиях андроида/хрома. А на дэсктопе это не работало в принципе никогда.